# initialize objects in numpy matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I would like to have a numpy matrix that is filled with unique objects. Currently I am creating a list of list and then converting it to a numpy array (see code below, under workaround). I am using it because I want to use slicing to access elements in the matrix

I was wondering if there was a better way to create such a matrix.

```
import random
import numpy as np

class RandomCell(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = random.randint(0, 10)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

# workaround
temp_matrix = [[RandomCell() for row in range(3)] for col in range(3)]
workaround_matrix = np.array(temp_matrix)
```

EDIT: I want to create a matrix of objects not generate a matrix of random numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method of building the array from a list of lists is fine. Another option would be

```
arr = np.array([RandomCell() for item in range(9)]).reshape(3,3)
```

Usually, to save memory you could use `np.fromiter` to build an array from an iterator. However, since this array has dtype `object`, unfortunately `np.fromiter` is not an option in this case.

Answer (score 1):

That's actually really simple

```
import numpy as np
np.random.randint(0, 10, (3,3))
```

Comment: I want to create objects. not generate random numbers. my apologies